# How to avoid bad color string error in Python turtle with Tkinter Text input?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm working on a project to control turtle from tkinter, but when I try to change the colour (to red) the code shows such an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\Lesson1\1.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    colourer = Button(text='Colour:', width=15, height=3, command=lambda: colour_change(colour, pen))
  File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\Lesson1\1.py", line 49, in colour_change
    feather.color(new_color)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2217, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 2697, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 1159, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: red
```

Here's the code (first you write the colour, then save the change and click on the 'Colour'):

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *

# Windows created
control = Tk()
pen = turtle.Turtle()
# A bit of design
# Button size: 15 = 115 px, 1 = 7 and 2/3 px
pen.shape('turtle')
control.title('Turtle controller v1.0')
control.geometry('345x168')
colour = ""


def colour_change(new_color, feather, hexa=False, rgb=False):
    if hexa is True:
        feather.color('#%s' % new_color)
    elif rgb is True:
        feather.colormode(255)
        feather.color(new_color)
    else:
        feather.color(new_color)


def changecolour():
    global colour
    colour = colourin.get(1.0, END)


colourer = Button(text='Colour', width=15, height=3, command=lambda: colour_change(colour, pen))
colourer.place(x=0, y=112)
colourin = Text(width=15, height=3)
colourin.place(x=115, y=112)
colourconv = Button(text='Save change', width=15, height=3, command=changecolour)
colourconv.place(x=230, y=112)
# Window mainloop
turtle.mainloop()
control.mainloop()
```

I tried to input Red, red and "red", none of which worked. I tried to debug myself - the transfer from Tkinter works perfectly, but the turtle does not accept the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is subtle. To debug this, examine the string with `repr()`:

```
colour = colourin.get(1.0, END)
print(repr(colour))
```

You'll see this prints:

```
'red\n'
```

Now the problem is clear: there's a trailing newline. Strip it:

```
colour = colourin.get(1.0, END).strip()
```

---

It's been pointed out in the comments that you can improve your Tkinter code a bit as well. `1.0` isn't a proper text index--prefer `"1.0"`.

`"end-1c"` instead of `END` will skip the last character, but I'd still `.strip()` anyway, since the user may have added arbitrary whitespace. Other validation and cleaning is likely necessary, depending on how you want to handle bad input.

Comment: FWIW, `1.0` isn't a proper text index. Tkinter will accept it, but indexes should be strings of the form _line.character_, not floating point numbers.  For example, the floating point `1.10` and the string index `"1.10"` do not represent the same character. Also, instead of stripping the newline you can use `"end-1c"` instead of `END` to get everything but the trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know anything about Tkinter. I'm a turtle guy. Would you mind editing the post or adding your own answer? I'll check the docs and update this when I have time.